# Libgdx PanStop missing

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have been using an InputHandler class which implements GestureListener and had some code in panStop. After I did an update of libgdx (on 18.05.14) for my project, @Override is no longer accepted for this method. Since then my logic is broken. I checked the GestureListener class and it's not in there.

Has it been removed? Should I be using something else from now on?

I was using it to be able to handle a tap while panning.

Comment: Its still there: http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/input/GestureDetector.GestureListener.html#panStop(float, float, int, int).  What is the exact error message you get from your `@Override`?  And what exactly does your `panStop` implementation signature look like?

Comment: The implementation I have is:

 @Override
 public boolean panStop (float x, float y, int pointer, int button) { 
  Gdx.app.log(TAG, "panStop");  
  reset();
  return false;
 }

and the error I get is the method panStop must override or implement a supertype method.

I import 
import com.badlogic.gdx.input.GestureDetector.GestureListener;

Comment: When I control click on GestureListener and go to the actual interface, I can see all the other methods (which still work for me) but I cannot see panStop.

Comment: Sorted it.. turns out the updater program was downloading an old version of the framework (pre 0.9.9 when the method was introduced). I manually downloaded the new one and loaded it in the updater and it worked.